# Why isn't the Static Pattern Rule working in my makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm new to Makefiles, so far I've only been doing little projects, but I just did my biggest project with 20 `*.c` files and put them all in a `src` file.

With my Makefile I wanted to create an `obj` file with all the corresponding `*.o` files and then make them all into an executable. I heard about [Static Patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) and I tried to use it on my makefile but I'm probably making a very silly mistake as the output is not what I expected.

My Makefile:

```
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror

MLX=mlx/libmlx_Darwin.a

LIBFT=libft/libft.a

I_LIBFT=-Ilibft -Llibft -lft

I_LIBMLX=-Imlx -Lmlx -lmlx

LIB=$(I_LIBFT) $(I_LIBMLX)

COMPATIBILITY=-lX11 -lXext

FRAMEWORK=-framework OpenGL -framework AppKit

HDR=/include/fdf.h

SRC_DIR=/src/

SRCS:=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)*.c)

OBJ_DIR=/obj/

OBJS=$(patsubst %.c, $(OBJ_DIR)%.o, $(SRCS))

all: $(LIBFT) app

$(LIBFT):
    make -C libft
    @echo "done libft"

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir $@
 
$(OBJS): $(OBJ_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.c $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 

app: $(OBJS)
    @echo "making app"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIB) $(FRAMEWORK) $(OBJS) -o FdF

clean:
    make -C libft $@

fclean: clean
    make -C libft $@

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re so
```

My output:

```
making app
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Ilibft -Llibft -lft -Imlx -Lmlx -lmlx -framework OpenGL -framework AppKit  -o FdF
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [app] Error 1
```

when I expected something like:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c file.c -o file.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c file2.c -o file2.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c file3.c -o file3.o
...
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Ilibft -Llibft -lft -Imlx -Lmlx -lmlx -framework OpenGL -framework AppKit file.o file2.o ... file19.o -o FdF
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SRC_DIR=/src/`. That will look for files in the root `/src` directory. Is that really what you want? Or do you actually want a relative directory: `SRC_DIR=src/` (no leading `/`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure these are wrong:

```
HDR=/include/fdf.h

SRC_DIR=/src/

OBJ_DIR=/obj/
```

Are your source and header files REALLY in a subdirectory of the root of your partition?  If you run `ls /src/` does it actually show any files?

I suspect that there is nothing there, which means that `SRCS` is empty because the wildcard expands to no matches, which means `OBJS` is empty since it's substituting into nothing, which means there are no prerequisites to the `app` target.